# Java Android For statement/loop parameters

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

Hello i've aquired some java code from an android sample project online and in the code there is a For statement/loop. The parameters for this For statement are displayed as (;;) rather than something like (int i = 0; i < string; i++). Can anyone explain exactly what this loop is doing by having the parameters as (;;)? i've tried researching online but can't find a thing!
thanks

```
for (;;) {

                len = mSerial.read(rbuf);
                rbuf[len] = 0;


                if (len > 0) {
                       //do something
   }
   }
```

Comment: It is ok to ask on stackoverflow, but trying wasn't hard :P

Comment: I just googled "for loop java". Here you go and you will find your answer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (;;)
```

is an infinite for loop as there is no exit condition.

**For loop syntax**

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //body
}
```

initialization,Boolean_expression,update, body: all of them are optional. The for loop keep executing until Boolean_expression till it is not false. If Boolean_expression is missing then for loop will never terminate.

Comment: ah of course!! very helpful, thank you, this makes total sense now!

Answer (score 4):

no initialisation, no exit condition, no increment.. it is a infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

It is an infinite loop. A for loop has 4 parts

```
for (initialisation; condition; increment/decrement) {
  loop body
}
```

You may choose to omit any of these parts (although some compilers may complain about the lack of a loop body and others will omit the entire loop for performance).

It is perfectly feasible that you may already have a variable initialised, and may skip the initialisation within the loop:

```
int i = 0;

for ( ; i < 10; i++ ) {
    // do something
}
```

It is also possible that you can choose to omit the incrementation, and do it elsewhere (be careful to include it inside the loop, otherwise this may lead to infinite loops unintentionally):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ) {
    // do something
    i++;
}
```

It is also possible to omit the conditional and include that elsewhere:

```
for ( int i = 0; ; i++ ) {
    // do something

    if (i == 9) {
      break;
    }
}
```

Or you can omit all of it entirely and make an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is an infinite loop that does something when the if condition is satisfied. It can be used if you are waiting for an input from the user untill then it loops foreever.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare for loop for (;;) .Every time loop will check the condition always it will return true so it goes in infinite loop.it is similar to **while(true)**.if you want to break the loop then yo need to add break statement then it will come out from infinite loop.